# Postgresql container automatically dropping database after some time in Docker Compose setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postgresql

I have a Docker Compose setup for a PostgreSQL container like below:

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PostgreSQL Service
  um-db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: um-db
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: user_management
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: postgresql
    volumes:
      - um-dbdata16:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - um-app-network

#Volumes
volumes:
  um-dbdata16:
    driver: local
```

After running `docker-compose up -d --build`, the database gets built successfully. However, after some time, it automatically gets dropped. Here's a snippet of the log:

```
docker logs um-db
2024-02-11 07:20:09.510 GMT [161] ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
2024-02-11 07:20:09.510 GMT [161] STATEMENT:  DROP DATABASE postgres;
2024-02-11 07:20:09.639 GMT [22] LOG:  checkpoint starting: immediate force wait
2024-02-11 07:20:10.449 GMT [165] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-02-11 07:20:10.449 GMT [165] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

The same setup is working fine on my Ubuntu server locally, but when deployed to a VPS, this issue occurs. I have thoroughly searched the internet for a solution but couldn't find any useful resources. Please point me in the right direction so that I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `2024-02-11 07:20:10.449 GMT [165] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`.

- Are you sure its the correct password?
- Your Volume is different from your Ubuntu machine to the VPS so check they are identical to rule out that issue.
- Check your `pg_hba.conf` on the line mentioned. You might have editited a line above or below and therefore the wrong permissions are set.
- You've not declared a `network:` section, is it on the same network as the thing your trying to connect to?

If these don't fix the issue, add your response & any other logs/errors and we will see fi we can get it sorted.